# eclipse code template like in visual studio to add template

Tags: c#, eclipse, visual-studio

If you had used eclipse. There is code template which allows you to add code template easily. 
Is there option for visual studio for c# programming?

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio there are [code snippets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/code-snippets), you can insert them via `right click -> snippet -> insert snippet` in code editor, or just type snippet shortcut and hit tab.

You can manage them (add new or edit existing ones) in `Tools -> Code Snippets Manager`.

To create your own you would have to create xml file and import it via this Code Snippets Manager. 
See more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/walkthrough-creating-a-code-snippet)